# How can I get UINavigationController.pushViewController to push on a presented viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

- I have initialized UINavigationController - `nc` with `VC0`
- I am in `VC0`
- In `VC0`, I want to present a `"VC1"` **bottom-to-top**
- In `VC0`, `[self.nc presentViewController:VC1]`
- Now I am in `VC1`
- In `VC1`, I want to present `VC2` **right-to-left**
- In `VC1`, I tried `[self.nc pushViewController:VC2]`
- But it does not work

How can I accomplish the above?

Comment: VC1 needs to be in its own UINavigationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC1 needs to be in its own UINavigationController. If you put a breakpoint at the point you try to call `pushViewController:animated:`, you'll notice that the navigation controller property on VC1 is `nil`.

When you present VC1 do this instead:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController completion:nil];
```

You can then do your `pushViewController:animated:` call.